# Traversing a linked-list

Tags: c#, linked-list

I created a simple node class, and solution class with an insert method, a display method, along with Main. I am trying to insert 4 numbers into the linked-list and have it display the entire list. At most I am only able to have it display 2 of the numbers. The issue is most likely in my insert method. I've spent hours trying to figure out what the issue is. What could be wrong with my code?

```
public static Node insert(Node head, int data)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            while (head.next != null)
            {
                head = head.next;
            }
            head.next = newNode;
        }
        return head;
    }

public static void display(Node head)
    {
        Node start = head;
        while (start != null)
        {
            Console.Write(start.data + " ");
            start = start.next;
        }
    }

static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        Node head = null;
        int[] numbers = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 1};
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            int data = numbers[i];
            head = insert(head, data);
        }
        display(head);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

class Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node next;
    public Node(int d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
    public Node() { }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to return `head` or *inserted node* - `newNode`?

Comment: I am trying to return the head. By doing so, my display method would return the entire list.

Comment: Could you, please, provide `Display` method, `Node` class with your *failed test*? If you want to return `head`, `Insert` method looks OK

Comment: Okay, I've just provided them. It should return 2,3,4,1 but it's just returning 4,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is in the `insert` method:

```
   while (head.next != null)
   {
        // From now on you have the initial head got lost
        head = head.next;
   }
```

Quick amendment is to change `while` into `for`:

```
    public static Node insert(Node head, int data) {
      Node newNode = new Node(data);
      
      if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
      }
      else {
        // we loop on last, keeping head intact 
        for (Node last = head; ; last = last.next)  
          if (last.next == null) {
            last.next = newNode;

            break;
          }
      }
      return head;
    }
```

we can simplify it further:

```
    public static Node insert(Node head, int data) {
      Node newNode = new Node(data);

      for (Node last = head; last != null; last = last.next)
        if (last.next == null) {
          last.next = newNode;

          return head;
        }

      return newNode;
    }
```

Comment: @UniqueHold: you can keep `while` loop, but in this case you should *save* the initial `head` in order to return it at the end.

Comment: Thanks! That info was just what I needed to make it work. Now I'm able to do it with either loops, I just need to better understand the concept behind it and I should be good to go.